# Why HikariCP connection works after idle timeout

Tags: java, jdbc, hikaricp

I am trying to test idle connections behavior. I am expecting my code to run into an exception here, but it doesn't:

```
static public void testConnectionDS() throws SQLException {
    HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
    ds.setJdbcUrl(Jdbc_URL);
    ds.setUsername(Username);
    ds.setPassword(Password);

    ds.setMaxLifetime(1000 * 60 * 3);
    ds.setMinimumIdle(2);
    ds.setIdleTimeout(1000 * 60 * 2);

    Connection connection = ds.getConnection();     
    
    setupTable(connection);
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(ds.getMaxLifetime() + ds.getIdleTimeout() + 1000 * 35); // around 6 miutes
        executeQuery(connection);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(java.time.LocalTime.now() + " : executeQuery Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

Priniting various setting, the seetings are:

```
KeepaliveTime:0
MaxLifetime:180,000
IdleTimeout:120,000
minimumIdle:2
maximumPoolSize:10
LeakDetectionThreshold:0
```

and my system settings is:

```
% sysctl -a |grep tcp |grep keep
net.inet.tcp.keepidle: 7200000
net.inet.tcp.keepintvl: 75000
net.inet.tcp.keepinit: 75000
net.inet.tcp.keepcnt: 8
net.inet.tcp.always_keepalive: 0
net.inet.mptcp.keepalive: 840
```

With `MaxLifetime` of 3 minutes, `IdleTimeout` of 2 minutes, `minimumIdle` < `maximumPoolSize` and disabled keepalive and leakdetection threshold, this connection should have not been able to execute `executeQuery`  function (which is a simple select query). But it does run into completion successfully.

What am I missing please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the meaning of `idleTimeout` in HikariCP: *"This property controls the maximum amount of time that a connection is allowed to sit idle in the pool."*. Your connection is not idle in the pool: your code has it checked out, so it's in use. Same with `maxLifeTime`: *" An in-use connection will never be retired, only when it is closed will it then be removed."* (quoted text from [HikariCP, Configuration (knobs, baby!)](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#gear-configuration-knobs-baby))

HikariCP doesn't have a way to forcibly close connections after a timeout. The only thing it has is `leakDetectionThreshold`, but that will just log that there is a potential connection leak, it will not revoke the connection.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrongplz: 
1- So the connection is considered idle if there is no handle to it. Once I do a `getConnection` it is considered not-idle until it is closed. 

2- My ultimate goal was to make sure I can use `setKeepaliveTime` beyond system's tcp keepalive (`net.inet.tcp.keepidle` in mac and tcp_keepalive_time in linux, both defaulted to 2 hours). I was trying to reduce the 2 hours and make a negative test. Do you think I can then just go ahead and set a high keepalive value beyond 2 hours, and the test would work?

Comment: I still need to know how to reproduce the scenario of an idle connection timeout, for which setting tcpkeepalive is a solution. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: @rahman You are confusing things here. The idle timeout of HikariCP is about the connections being evicted from the connection pool when they haven't been used in a while, the keep alive time / keep idle is a low level mechanism to ensure TCP/IP connections which are open but not actively used are kept open. If you want to see idle time at work, make sure you open more connections than the minimumIdle setting (so they have actually been created), then close them all (so they are returned to the pool) and then wait the idle-time duration (+ some slack).

Comment: @rahman HikariCP should then trim the number of connections in the pool back to minimumIdle.